# Stencil, How to send data from child component to parent component when i click on button in a parent component

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs

I have a stencil child component that contains my form and I have another parent component that calls the child component and adds the submit button. I would like to retrieve a string or a boolean in the child component when I validate the form (when I click on the submit button which is in the parent component).

.I want to know if all the fields in the form are valid. I don't want to listen to the child component with OnChange and @listen, I want to get the exact validation at the time of form submission

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is fairly straightforward to implement by adding a Method to the child component:

Parent

```js
private formComponent;
...
render() {
    return <Host>
        <child-component ref={ el => this.formComponent = el }></child-component>
        <button onClick={ () => this.formComponent.isValid() }>Submit</button>
    </Host>;
}
```

Child

```js
@Method() isValid(): boolean {
    ...
}
render() {
    return <Host>
        <form>
            ...
        </form>
    </Host>;
}
```